# Change InoNet BIOS Settings by script

Tags: bios, script, administration

I have to change the BIOS settings of many InoNet computers. Are there a tool or a script for it? I can find PowerShell based libraries for HP, Dell an Lenovo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for PowerShell commands to change BIOS settings,
see the article
[List and change BIOS settings with PowerShell](http://www.systanddeploy.com/2019/03/list-and-change-bios-settings-with.html).

The article lists these PowerShell classes:

- HP : Namespace `root/hp/instrumentedBIOS`, Class `hp_biosEnumeration`
- DELL : Module `DellBIOSProvider`, path `DellSmbios:\`
- LENOVO : class `Lenovo_BiosSetting`, namespace `root\wmi`

For further information you may google for the above names.

For example, this one might be useful :
[Lenovo BIOS Setup using WMI Deployment Guide](https://www.mediasupport.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/skl_deploy_01.pdf).